# The module "APT50.dll" failed to load

Tags: command-prompt

I'm trying to register the APT50.dll using the regsvr32 command in command prompt (running in admin mode) and I keep getting the error message:

"The module 'APT50.dll' failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified module could not be found."

I'm positive that my file path is correct, so what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT50.dll (AKA active pdf) requires certain credentials to be accessed. I did not have these credentials. It's not free.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is drawn from [Fixing RegSvr32 The module failed to load. The specified module could not be found on Windows 64-bit](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/73-windows-64-bit/378-fixing-qregsvr32-the-module-failed-to-load-the-specified-module-could-not-be-foundq).

If you're running a 64 bit version of Windows, and if apt50.dll is 32 bit, then when regsvr32 is run and attempts to access System32 it is automatically redirected to the SysWOW64 folder instead.

The solution is to place apt50.dll int he SysWOW64 folder instead, which should mean that regsvr32 correctly loads the module.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late... but I am adding my solution for others because I faced the same error after following above mentioned answers:

"The solution is to place apt50.dll int he SysWOW64 folder instead, which should mean that regsvr32 correctly loads the module."

If you are facing same error after placing DDL to SysWOW64, then you need to turn on MSMQ feature.

Go to Start -> Search "Turn Windows features on or off" -> Find "Microsoft Message Queue(MSMQ) Server" and Enable it.

[image]

Now, register the same DLL again and this time it will be registered